# How to query for dn in Active Directory below non-leaf user object when the child object has no attributes?

Tags: vbscript, attributes, active-directory, ldap-query

Basically, what I'm trying to accomplish is deleting a non-leaf user object from MS Active Directory. At some point in time, a few additional objects were put underneath these non-leaf user objects, so I am trying to query for all these objects underneath the base and remove them first.

Here is my query in VBScript:

```
qQuery = "<LDAP://[SERVERNAME]/[BASE_USER_OBJECT]>;" & _
"(objectCategory=*);dn
```

I am expecting this to return the `dn` of every object below my base user object. The script throws an "Unspecified Error".

If I change the requesting attributes to `distinguishedName` instead of `dn`, then it runs just fine and returns the `distinguishedName` attribute from a few of the child objects. The problem is that a majority of the child objects don't have this `distinguishedName` attribute, or ANY attribute for that matter.

Is there any way to query for the `dn` in VBScript?

Thank you for any help in advance!

Comment: If the objects don't have any attributes, what exactly are they?  Other OUs?

Comment: @Kodra It's another CN underneath the base. They were put there for some application to use single sign on. They are not needed anymore, and I need to clean them up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guaranteed the objects have a `distinguishedName`. It's mandatory. Do you have enough permission to see these objects?

This link has a number of good examples for your situation - http://www.selfadsi.org/delete.htm.

Comment: You were correct. I had to bind as a domain admin in order to see the `distinguishedName` attribute. Thank you.